# Pandas: Map DF with multiple columns to another

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to map `df2` to `df1`.  What makes this a bit trickier, is the *key* can sometimes be a tuple of 2+ `keys`.

Keys (the a, b, c's) are indeed strings.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Index':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'key':['a','a','b',('a','c'),'c',('a','b','c'),'b','a']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Index':[a,b,c],'Val1':[1,2,3],'Val2':[.1,.2,.3],'Val3':[10,20,30],'Val4':[1,2,3],'Val5':[2,4,6]})
```

Basically, I am trying to map `df2` (via the *Index*) to the *key* in `df1`.  The end result would have `columns = [key, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5]`, and in the result that the `type(key) == tuple`, I would like a tuple of the 2+ matched Vals.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe post your desired output. It's not clear what you need.

Comment: And a valid reproducible input. Please quote the letters.

Comment: sorrry, I blame not having done all that on my two kids

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about data types, I think you are trying to join/merge in (a,b,c) variables and getting the error:

> TypeError: Unhashable Type: 'List'

If I'm right, you should build a dictionary {index:value}, with index = integers and value = tuples of objects. Then, replace, do your join/merge/whatever and replace again.

Considering pandas.replace will fail with "weird" data types, you will need one dict and filter the dataframe for each data type.

That's a generic answer for a generic question. For a precise answer, specify (a,b,c) data types at least.